# How Web Server responds when it gets "Options" Request?

Tags: java, http, webserver, httpwebresponse, http-options-method

I want to implement Options method in my HTTP web server. But I didn't yet find the good tutorial of the working of this method. I made one code that implements this method, my code is at the end of this question.

But I think the working of server I used is wrong. Can you tell me the exact method/ steps how server respond, when it gets Options request. Waiting for you kind response.

**Client Code**

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
          client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Test Client");

          OptionsMethod method = new OptionsMethod("http://localhost:8080");          

          try {
            int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
            if(returnCode == 405 ) {
                System.out.println("The Options method is not implemented by this URI");
            } else {
                Header[] header = method.getResponseHeaders();
                for(int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                   System.out.println(header[i].getName() + ": " + header[i].getValue());
                }
            }
          } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Options method ki to TAI TAI FISSHHHHHH");
          } finally {
                System.out.println("close method");
                method.releaseConnection();
         }
    }
}
```

**Server Code (my server allows PUT, POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS methods)**

```
    printStream.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    printStream.write(Worker.EOL);
    printStream.print("Date: " + new Date());
    printStream.write(Worker.EOL);
    printStream.print("Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT");
    printStream.write(Worker.EOL);
    printStream.print("Content-Length: 0");
    printStream.write(Worker.EOL);
    printStream.write(Worker.EOL);
```

**Is this a correct way to respond by the server? If not please tell me the server working when it gets Options Request ?**

Comment: @All If anyone knows, please help me.